# How to send complete POST request using Net::HTTP (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to send a complete request like this:

```
POST /2012-09-25/jobs HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Host: elastictranscoder.amazonaws.com:443
x-amz-date: Mon, 14 Jan 2013 17:49:52 GMT
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 
           Credential=AccessKeyID/request-date/Elastic Transcoder endpoint/ets/aws4_request,
           SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target,
           Signature=calculated-signature
Content-Length: number of characters in the JSON string
{
"Input":{
  "Key":"AAAA",
  "FrameRate":"auto",
  "Resolution":"auto",
  "AspectRatio":"auto",
  "Interlaced":"auto",
  "Container":"auto"
},
"Output":{
  "Key":"BBBB",
  "ThumbnailPattern":"pattern",
  "Rotate":"auto",
  "PresetId":"12345"
},
"PipelineId":"987654"
}
```

How to make it with `Net::HTTP` in Rails?

Answer (score 3):

Check out these, POST form request, File upload - input type="file" style

http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html

https://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet

Comment: I follow this link https://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet/blob/master/post_form.rb then I got error "getaddrinfo: Name or service not known" u know what is it ?